# Regex to Capitalize words between tags

Tags: xml, notepad++

I have a few XML files in Notepad++ that contain a lot of names between the following two tags:

```
<givenName>John</givenName>
<surname>Doe</surname>

<givenName>Jane</givenName>
<surname>Doe</surname>
```

I would need the regular expressions that would convert the names between both tags to obtain this result:

```
<givenName>JOHN</givenName>
<surname>DOE</surname>

<givenName>JANE</givenName>
<surname>DOE</surname>
```

I've done a lot of research but I'm only seeing cases where users are trying to capitalize the first letter after a tag but not the entire word.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    <([^>]+)>(.*)<\/\1>
Replace: <$1>\U$2\E</$1>
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
<([^>]+)>   match an opening XML tag, and capture the name in \1 or $1
(.*?)       then match and capture the name inside the tag
<\/\1>       match a closing tag, which agrees with the opening tag
```

Then, we replace with the same tag, converting the name to uppercase using `\U` and terminate the uppercase transformation with '\E' so that the closing tag remains unaffected.

Comment: Good, but won't work when the tag has attributes. I'd search with "<([^\s>]+)(.+)?>(.+)?<\/(\1)>" instead (edgecases not really relevant to the question though)

Comment: Would replace commented out tags, as well, and won't handle names if expressed as CDATA.

Comment: To address both of your comments: If these be a real concern, then use an XML parser, not regex.  The OP made zero mention of either of these edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

For handling XML, don't use regexes, use an XML-aware tool. For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) (a tool I happen to maintain) you can write

```
open file.xml ;
for (//givenName/text() | //surname/text())
    set . xsh:uc(.) ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: This is by far better than any regex-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<(givenName|surname)[^>]*>\K(\w+)(?=</\1>)`
- Replace with: `\U$2`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<               # literally <
(               # start group 1
  givenName     # literally
 |              # OR
  surname       # literally
)               # end group 1
[^>]*           # 0 or more non >, for optional attributes
>               # literally <
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
(\w+)           # group 2, 1 or more word character, you can replace with (.+?) if you have other characters than word characters
(?=</\1>)       # positive lookahead, make sure we have the corresponding closing tag after
```

**Replacement:**

```
\U          # uppercase the following
$2          # content of group 2
```

**Result for given example:**

```
<givenName>JOHN</givenName>
<surname>DOE</surname>

<givenName>JANE</givenName>
<surname>DOE</surname>
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: @choroba The OP only mentioned two types of XML tags, neither of which have any attributes.

Comment: @Omokocha: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)